# How to speed up copying data from six S3 buckets to another six S3 buckets using AWS CLI in Github Actions job

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions, aws-cli

I have a Github Actions job that copies data from 6 S3 buckets to another 6 S3 buckets. The problem is that the process takes about 30 minutes to complete as I have to clear the destination buckets before copying the data.

Here is the code for the Github Actions job:

```
  restore-s3:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 60
    steps:
      - name: Assume Role
        uses: youyo/awscredswrap@v1.0.4
        with:
          role_arn: ${{ secrets.AWS_EKS_IAM_ROLE }}
          duration_seconds: 3600
          role_session_name: EKS
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ env.AWS_ECR_REGION }}
      - name: restore S3 data
        id: s3_dir
        run: |
          release_version=${{ inputs.data_version }}
          echo $release_version
          aws s3 rm --recursive s3://test.qa.avatar.file-2027145436775700000001/ &
          aws s3 rm --recursive s3://test.qa.avatar.origin-2027145436939200000007/ &
          aws s3 rm --recursive s3://test.qa.documents.original-2027145436794600000003/ &
          aws s3 rm --recursive s3://test.qa.documents.sdf-2027145436895500000005/ &
          aws s3 rm --recursive s3://test.qa.templates.original-2027145436908800000006/ &
          aws s3 rm --recursive s3://test.qa.templates.sdf-2027145436788200000002/ &
          wait
          aws s3 cp --recursive "s3://test.qa.avatar.file/$release_version/" s3://test.qa.avatar.file-2027145436775700000001/ &
          aws s3 cp --recursive "s3://test.qa.avatar.origin/$release_version/" s3://test.qa.avatar.origin-2027145436939200000007/ &
          aws s3 cp --recursive "s3://test.qa.documents.original/$release_version/" s3://test.qa.documents.original-2027145436794600000003/ &
          aws s3 cp --recursive "s3://test.qa.documents.sdf/$release_version/" s3://test.qa.documents.sdf-2027145436895500000005/ &
          aws s3 cp --recursive "s3://test.qa.templates.original/$release_version/" s3://test.qa.templates.original-2027145436908800000006/ &
          aws s3 cp --recursive "s3://test.qa.templates.sdf/$release_version/" s3://test.qa.templates.sdf-2027145436788200000002/ &
          wait
          echo "Restore completed"
```

Will GitHub action's matrix strategy works for my case?

P.S I also tried creating python boto script but it difference was not significant

Comment: I am not familiar with aws s3. From my point of view, you wait until the last delete job has been processed before you start copying the first data. With bash I would try the following with every of your 6 jobs: `(rm -r ... && cp -r ...) &` I don't know if it is possible with aws s3.

Comment: Or rename the 6 directories, copy the data as before and finally delete the renamed directories.

Comment: you could probably try

`aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 20`

Comment: @Cyrus Just an FYI, it is not possible to rename directories in Amazon S3. It is a 'flat' storage system. Each object has a unique identifier that includes the _full path_. The appearance of folders/directories is merely to assist humans.

Comment: Which part takes the most time? Is it the deletion process or the copy process? If it is the deletion step, you might be able to write your own code that deletes multiple objects in a single API call. I suspect that the AWS CLI deletes one object per API call.

Comment: You might look into s3 object versioning and/or s3 bucket lifecycle configuration as alternatives to API-based recursive deletions.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/manage-objects-versioned-bucket.html

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Copy process takes the most